# how to render equally sized tables in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Basically I got an array of 4 objects, each of these objects contains a array that i want to render into a table. But the sub arrays are of different sizes and I need the tables to have the same amount of rows (rendering just empty cels for where i have no data)

The data would look something like this:

```
App.budgetdata = [
    Ember.Object.create({
        omschrijving: 'Week',
        rules: [
            Em.Object.create({
                omschrijving: 'zakgeld',
                bedrag: 20.00,
                richting: 'af'
            })
        ]
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        omschrijving: 'Maand',
        'default': true,
        rules: [
            Em.Object.create({
                omschrijving: 'salaris',
                bedrag: 1300.00,
                richting: 'bij'
            }),
            Em.Object.create({
                omschrijving: 'internet',
                bedrag: 60.00,
                richting: 'af'
            }),
            Em.Object.create({
                omschrijving: 'auto kosten',
                bedrag: 300.00,
                richting: 'af'
            })
        ]
    }),

    Ember.Object.create({
        omschrijving: 'Kwartaal',
        rules: [
            Em.Object.create({
                omschrijving: 'sp',
                bedrag: 5.00,
                richting: 'af'
            })
        ]
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        rules: [

        ]
    }),
];
```

How can I make emberjs render this into 4 tables that have a equal number of rows (so these would all have 4 rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, Bassicly i made a property for the maximal size in the array controller, then i displayed the sub arrays within a collection view that had that maximal size bound to it.

After that i could easily define a content property that had equaly sized arrays.